# Access Auto-Increment Value During INSERT INTO Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, auto-increment, insert-into

I am currently using MySQL. I have a table that has an auto_increment 'id' field, and an 'imgname' field containing a string that is the file name of an image.

I need to generate the 'imgname' value using the auto_increment value that is create by an INSERT INTO statement. The problem is, I don't know this value until I can use mysql_insert_id, AFTER the insert query has run. I would like to know if it's possible to access this value DURING the insert query somehow and then use it to generate my string in the query statement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the `id` and `imgname` independent of each other and combine the two on `SELECT` when needed. If the need is frequent enough, [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

Comment: This might be the best idea, but I really would like to do what I asked in my question if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function. If performance is not an issue, `INSERT` regularly, and then `UPDATE` using `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, like:

```
UPDATE table SET name = CONCAT(name, "-", LAST_INSERT_ID()) WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am currently doing, but I want to do it with one single query if possible.