# INSERT query using ID

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access Auto-Increment Value During INSERT INTO Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932339/access-auto-increment-value-during-insert-into-statement)

I want to run an INSERT query on a table like for example with 2 fields: id, name.

However I want to use the id in the name field, such as to prepend the id to the name. Now I could INSERT and then use PHP to to get the last id and then UPDATE the name based on that. However I would like to avoid using more than 1 query for this. I could use the auto increment value but that is not safe since another query can be run in between getting the ID and running the INSERT. So is there safe way to use the id in a field?

Comment: What's the utility of this approach? You can concat them at presentation level.

Comment: In case data is moved or something and ID's for some reason or another are screwed up in anyway, unlikely I know.

Comment: nick is right: it's useless to duplicate the data - it'll only cause errors. Just put the ID in the ID, and the NAME in the NAME. Then do a `SELECT ID, CONCAT(ID," ",NAME) AS NAME FROM TABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it in a single query. However you can safely use UPDATE with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` because `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is safe. It will always return last ID inserted in current session (even if there are other sessions doing inserts at the same time)

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: @Anonymous; you can use this advice with PHP's **mysqli.multi-query()**: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @ypercube: true, but running two consecutive `mysql[i]_query`s will work just as well, provided they will use the same connection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an update query like this one to make sure you get the correct id

```
update myTable set name = concat(id, name) where <where condition>
```

if you want to add a space between the id and name simply use `concat(id, ' ', name)`.

And if you really really want to do it in just one query I reckon it would be something like this:

```
insert into myTable values(null, concat((select auto_increment from 
information_schema.tables where table_schema = myDatabaseSchema and
table_name = myTable), <name data>));
```

EDIT: Ignore this max(id) thing - as pointed out in comments.

```
insert into myTable values(null, concat((select max(id)+1 
from myTable), <name data>));
```

However, you should avoid duplicating data like that, and simply concat it when selecting.

Comment: `MAX(ID)+1` does not ensure you will get the same value as from AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: No, you're right. If rows are being deleted as well it won't be usable at all. My bad.

Comment: Not only then. When an insert query is done in transaction and rolled back, the AUTO_INCREMENT is increased anyway. Also in multimaster replication setups AUTO_INCREMENTs are not necessarily sequential.

Comment: Actually I didn't take that into account with regards to the question asked, but you're completely right. Added a query which utilises the information_schema data to get the auto_increment value instead. If someone really wants to do it in one statement I could atleast supply something somewhat useful.

Comment: `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT` is clever, but also does not ensure you will actually get same value. `information_schema` views are not transaction safe, and there's still possibilty, that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment is set to 2 or more

Comment: In a transaction intensive table it would indeed render inconsistency between the concatenated id and the autoset one. However in a low-insert-frequency table it should work quite well, not flawless, but quite well. And if you do know of a safer way for someone who really, badly, wants to do this in one statement, instead of running an update afterwards (as the one in my answer) - if they really want to duplicate the data like that, please let me know.

Comment: @johangu: Mchl stated in his answer that there is no way to achieve that in one statement.

Comment: I do not know such way, that's why I wrote in my answer, that there isn't one.