# Create slug to include id and title when insert record - php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access Auto-Increment Value During INSERT INTO Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932339/access-auto-increment-value-during-insert-into-statement)

I would like to generate the slug for my URLs upon creating the pages to store in the database. The slug should be `title-id` (e.g `titlename-234`). I already have the function to strip the title but how can i get the id before inserting the record?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can't unless you assign it yourself; you'd have to update your row after the insert or just stick the ID at the end when you generate the url.

Comment: Pretty much the same question here: [Access Auto-Increment Value During INSERT INTO Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932339/access-auto-increment-value-during-insert-into-statement)

Comment: ok cheers. i really prefer to have the url in the DB, so i guess i will have to update after insert. cheers..... @TimLytle cheers I will have a look at that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a trigger, something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW SET slug = CONCAT(NEW.title, "-", NEW.id);
```

I'm not sure you'll be able to access the ID column before its written on the database (unless, of course, you generate your IDs yourself, not using the autoincrement).

If you're using your DB's autoincrement (and you should be), try creating a trigger AFTER INSERT, and updating your row in your trigger. That way, even though you're updating it AFTER your insert, it'll still run before you can run any other queries (like a SELECT).

[HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) is the documentation on triggers.

---

I was wrong. Apparently, you can't update a table you're inserting into (using an AFTER INSERT triger), it'll throw an exception. So, two possible ways to do it using SQL alone:

The ugly way:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `create_slug` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `events`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET new.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM events) + 1;
    SET new.slug = CONCAT(new.menu_name, "-", new.id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

It overrides your database's AUTOINCREMENT. Really, don't do that.

Or, you can create a procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_event(MenuName VARCHAR(30), Content TEXT, PhotoName TEXT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO events (menu_name, content, photo_name) VALUES (MenuName, Content, PhotoName);
    SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    UPDATE events SET slug = CONCAT(menu_name, "-", @id) WHERE id = @id;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And, instead of calling (as you were calling):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events (menu_name, content, photo_name) VALUES ('{$menu_name}', '{$content}', '{$photo_name}');", $connection);
```

just call

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL insert_event('{$menu_name}', '{$content}', '{$photo_name}');",$connection );
```

Again, I'll strongly advice against using mysql_query. It's outdated, discontinued and unsafe. You should check out mysqli or PDO.

Comment: that sounds great. Thanks i will try that for sure. Many thanks indeed. and yes i am using auto inc IDs :)

Comment: You are welcome. Also remember to create a trigger when you update the row (or else, if you change your 'title', you'll still be stuck with your previous slug). Try it out and if it works, please remember to come back and accept the answer :)

Comment: I'm getting an error, can you see anything wrong with my code? `$query = "INSERT INTO events (
      menu_name, content, photo_name
     ) VALUES (
      '{$menu_name}', '{$content}', '{$photo_name}'
     )
     CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON events
FOR EACH ROW SET slug = CONCAT(NEW.menu_name, "-", NEW.id)";
   $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);`

Comment: Just added an example to help you out.

Comment: Oh! You cannot run two queries inside your mysql_query function call. Also, a trigger is not something you run inside your insert statement. Just go into your database and create this trigger (you only create the trigger once, and it will trigger everytime you insert something into events).

Comment: Just added the final code for your case. Hope that helps.

Comment: I already created the trigger using the first script :(  now when trying to insert the second it throws an error `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'` and now i cant upload a new event either. is there a way i can delete the trigger and start again?

Comment: Go in your database and run the following query: DROP TRIGGER my_trigger;

Comment: Cheers, i was using DELETE instead of DROP haha... Ok so i did that but now when i go to create an entry i get this error `Subject creation failed.

Can't update table 'events' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.` do you have any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19301/discussion-between-pedro-cordeiro-and-robolist)